# Can't access map[string]*someStruct correctly

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how to access struct files of map the right way.

I have two structs

```
type ZipStructure struct {
    Pfx  []byte
    Cert []byte
    Key  []byte
    Json []byte
}
```

```
type ServerConfig struct {
    ClusterSetupZip  map[string]ZipStructure
}
```

I want to allocate space to the map and access the fields of `ZipStructure`.

For example, `zs[DirName].Pfx = bytes`

It's only possible if I change the declaration of the `map` to `map[string]*ZipStructure`

Although I'm getting an `NRE`

I was also trying to allocate space this way `make(map[string]*ZipStructure`, 4)` and it also didn't help.

Comment: If you use pointer you need to initialize the individual elements before trying to access their fields because the zero value for a pointer is `nil` and therefore the expression `m[k].f` will panic. If you use a non pointer you can't use `m[k].f = x` because `m[k]` will return a copy of the element inside the map which makes the whole assignment void, which is why it's not allowed.

Comment: what is the proper way to initialize the elements in this case? expect creating a `var name ZipStructure` and doing the assignment in two phases?

Comment: Yes, if you are using non-pointer structs you first need to read the struct from the map and assign it to a variable, then modify the fields through the variable, and then update the struct in the map using `m[k] = v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the struct in the stored map, you can check if it exists or not, then create it:

```
if _, found := zs[DirName]; !found {
    zs[DirName] = &ZipStructure{
        //If you need, you can initialize the slices also here
        Pfx:  make([]byte,0),
        Cert: make([]byte,0),
        Key:  make([]byte,0),
        Json: make([]byte,0),
    }
}
//Now its accessible
zs[DirName].Pfx = append(zs[DirName].Pfx,b)
```

Comment: This is awesome. Tnx